Another "Failed to spawn helper" error on Lunux Ubuntu Jenkins build node?
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.11 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+9-Ubuntu-120.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+9-Ubuntu-120.04.2, mixed mode, sharing)

I've read Java, Failed to exec spawn helper error since moving to Java 14 on linux and Failed to exec spawn helper, and their solutions talk about:

setting -Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork and restarting
jenkins.service
Stopping Gradle daemon
Add executable permissions to /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/jspawnhelper

In my case this is randomly happening on our Linux Ubuntu build nodes running JDK17 and none of the solutions above (and others mentioned in the post) apply. Our build nodes don't run jenkins.service (We run Jenkins as a Docker container in our master node) so there's nothing to set and restart, and the problem happens on non-
Gradle steps. /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/jspawnhelper has executable permissions. Here's an example of a stacktrace
java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 87886, exit value: 1
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to i-0df1a5cb61bd62363
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1003)
        at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:1121)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:180)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:134)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:329)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:323)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor447.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:105)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor424.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor429.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:17)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:49)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:423)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 803e0923-3bed-49f4-b1c1-ff780f6b371e
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "/home/jenkins/workspace/Utilities/ECS-microservice-sandbox-scaleup"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 87886, exit value: 1
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:994)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1395)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1337)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Finished: FAILURE

The error above shows nohup failing to spawn (we run sh "..." commands, which spawns nohup), but I've seen it fail similarly with docker ... and git ... commands.
Any ideas how I can debug and possible solve this for my case? Thanks!

i'm going to try docker run ... JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork". Does the last key/value pair apply to a docker container?
